# How can i generate a formatted random string using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I generate a formatted random string in reactjs using this format NR${currentYear}${lastNumber + 1} in which it will give out the output: NR20201

Comment: Can you clarify which part is random? It looks like it's just the text "NR" with the current year and a counter.

Comment: What has that got to do with React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
function solution() {
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
  lastNumber = parseInt(currentYear.toString().split('').pop())
  return `NR${currentYear}${lastNumber + 1}`
}
```

Output:

```
NR20201
```

Comment: btw, the solution is agnostic to the js framework, it's nothing but plain js

Comment: Yhh Thanks @David

Comment: But what if i want it to keep on generating unique strings but still with same NR${currentYear} format then what comes after can just be any random number